# How to add calculations to OLAP cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, olap, cube

I created some calculations. How to add this calculations from Calculations tab:
[image]

to Cube Structure:

[image]

in Analysis Services.

Comment: Why? Can you provide more background on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @GregGalloway I would like to give users the ability to use it in browsing.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. Users can browse calculated measures. Can you describe more what's going on? What client tool? Can you provide a screenshot of a calculated measure users can't see? Do you have any Perspectives created and do they include the calculated measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add calculations to the cube structure tab, and you're not supposed to.

The calculations in the calculations tab are in the cube, and can be browsed by end users.

They don't show up in the cube structure tab for the same reason dimension usage doesn't show up in the cube structure tab.   That's not what that tab is for.   That's just the way Microsoft designed BIDS to work.